# Shortcode to show current post category with link

Tags: shortcode, post-meta

I want to display the current post category with link using shortcode **[post_category]**. The current code I got below shows the current category as text. I want it to be a link to the category. Thanks.

```
function category_name_shortcode(){
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $catName = "";
    foreach((get_the_category($post_id)) as $category){
        $catName .= $category->name . " ,";
    }
    return $catName;
}
add_shortcode('post_category','category_name_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to modify your current code and add the links in there:

```
function category_name_shortcode() {
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $catName = "";
    foreach((get_the_category($post_id)) as $category){
        $catName .= '<a href="' . get_term_link($category) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>, ';
    }
    return $catName;
}
add_shortcode( 'post_category', 'category_name_shortcode' );
```

But there’s an easier way, because WP already has a way to obtain the list of categories with links ([`get_the_category_list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_list/)):

```
function category_name_shortcode() {
    return get_the_category_list( ', ' );
}
add_shortcode( 'post_category', 'category_name_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Thanks. This works.